# Variable Height of TextView In TableView Cell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a basic `UITableView`, that I fill with a web service online, but I can't find a way to set the height of my cells (dynamic numbers of cells) according to the height of my `textView`.

Here's how I fill my cell :

```
UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)[cell viewWithTag:106];
textView.text = [[stories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"texte"];
```

in my `cellForRow` methods :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I tried this but get an error of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

```
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PerleCell"];
    UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)[cell viewWithTag:106];
    textView.text = [[stories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"texte"];
    CGFloat *heightCell =  (CGFloat*)textView.text.length;
    return *heightCell;
}
```

Comment: Hello dear take a look on my code and reply me if you will get any problem. Rememmber during creating never deque cell. always create new cell and modify that cell as you want and then add return that cell.

Comment: Not dequeuing cells is bad advise, and will make your app use more memory than it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In following method you can change height of your cell according to your textView.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    // Here check length of your textView
    // and after getting length return that length;
    NSString *myString = [[stories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"texte"];
    CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(300, 9999);
    UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
    CGSize myStringSize = [myString sizeWithFont:myFont constrainedToSize:maximumSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return size.height;
}
```

Also in cellForRowAtIndexPath method calculate width of string in same manner and then give frame of width of yourtextView accordingly. After that add your textview on cell's contentView.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     // Create cell here by using any style and for this you can google some what that how to create cell in UITableView
     // Here check length of your textView
     // and after getting length return that length;
     NSString *myString = [[stories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"texte"];
     CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(300, 9999);
     UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
     CGSize myStringSize = [myString sizeWithFont:myFont constrainedToSize:maximumSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
     UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,size.height)];
     textView.text = myString;
     [cell.contentView addSubView:textView];
     return cell;
}
```

Comment: Also while dequeCell never use reuseIdentifier, because you cells are of different sizes and it will create problems. I have not tested it but I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thnaks for ur answer but i edit my question with your suggestion and got an error :s

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the return

Comment: Why are you trying to access cell here. Only create textView and then calculate height of that textView

Comment: Thx for the code, but I don't understand your "self.myLabel.lineBreakMode" lineBreakMode !

Comment: That is UILineBreakModeWordWrap or any type of lineBreakMode. see my edit now

Comment: Your comment about not reusing cells is incorrect. You should reuse the cells for efficiency, and all the resizing should be done in heightForRowAtIndexPath: not in cellForRowAtIndexPath:. Reused cells will have their size reset by heightForRowAtIndexPath: before they're reused, so that shouldn't be a problem. I don't know if it makes any difference, but I use a multi-line label for this kind of thing rather than a text view.

Comment: Ok, I did not tested it. It was only my suggestion.